# With data.table, is SD[which.max(Var1)] the fastest way to find the max of a group?

Tags: r, data.table

If needed I can put together a dataset, but my question is somewhat general.

```
accts <- accts[, .SD[which.max(EE)], by=DnB.Name]
```

I've got a DT of about 350k rows, and some of the DnB.Name's (Duns and Bradstreet Company Name) are duplicates with differing employee counts (EE), I only care about the highest number of each and can disregard the rest.

Anyway, DT is usually lightning quick, so I figure I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably to do with using `.SD`, which means you are having to load a whole chunk of your `data.table` for each `by` group. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707368/finding-the-index-of-a-max-value-in-r

Comment: The fastest way currently would be to use `.I` instead as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/559784). In your case, just replace the expression inside to `.I[which.max(..)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort by EE, then take the first row for each group using a self join:

```
 ordered<-accts[order(-EE)] #Descending order
 setkey(ordered,DnB.Name) #must setkey before join
 ordered[J(unique(DnB.Name)),mult="first"]
```

For reference, check out this post on crossvalidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier

EDIT: even faster, but weird syntax:

```
accts[accts[, .I[which.max(EE)], by = DnB.Name]$V1]
```

For reference, check this post with a similar question:
[Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table/16574176#16574176)

Comment: clever, still really slow though.  But I think this is the right direction.  How would I keep the first instance of each DnB.Name but remove duplicates without the .SD, because I think what's going on is that since duplicates are rare, it's subsetting 340k times

Comment: try the self join method

Comment: what is the ID variable?

Comment: sorry, was thinking generally, updated with DnB.name. This should be lightning fast.

Comment: I see, gotta keep the first line, skip the second, then proceed with your edit but ID should be DnB.Name.  Brilliant, super crazy quick.  Make those last edits and I'll give you the check mark :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Although the solution using `.I` is a bit confusing to the average data.table user. I'm sure you guys have plans to implement that under the hood so the user is abstracted from it. I'm certainly not complaining ;)

Comment: Yo dawg, I hear you like data.tables, so I put a data.table in a data.table..... errr  couldn't resist.  Could you explain what's going on in your exotic second solution?  I didn't realize you could nest data.tables in data.tables, aside from joins... then again, maybe I just answered my own question?