# Missing columns when using max in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get the top frequency words in a data.table

data.table : dtable4G

```
key              freq     value
================================
thanks for the   612      support
thanks for the   380      drink
thanks for the   215      payment
thanks for the    27      encouragement
have a great     154      day
have a great     132      weekend
have a great      54      week  
have a great      42      time
have a great      19      night
at the same      346      time
at the same       57      damn
at the same       30      pace
at the same       11      speed
at the same        7      level
at the same        1      rate
```

I tried the code

```
dtable4G[ , max(freq), by = key]
```

and

```
dtable4G[ , .I[which.max(freq)] , by = key]
```

Both the above commands, I am getting the same result:

```
key              V1
====================
thanks for the   612
have a great     154
at the same      346
```

I want the result to be:

```
key              freq     value
================================
thanks for the   612      support
have a great     154      day
at the same      346      time
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDITED**

dtable4G[dtable4G[, .I[which.max(freq)], by = key]$V1]

worked for me. Though it took some time to run through my 5.4 mil rows.

But this was way faster than using

```
dtable4G[,.SD[which.max(freq)],by=key]
```

Reference: [With data.table, is SD[which.max(Var1)] the fastest way to find the max of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419683/with-data-table-is-sdwhich-maxvar1-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-max-of-a-gro?lq=1)

Comment: Have you tried using the `list operator ".()"`

Comment: @Codexer,  can you please elaborate? I am new to this and not sure what you mean.

Comment: Try `dtable4G[ , .(value,max(freq)), by = key]`

Comment: @Codexer, that did not work. It just copied over all the rows and updated the freq with the highest for each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the data table for only the max freq of each `key` column value with the following:

```
dtable4G[,.SD[which.max(freq)],by=key]
```

For better performance you can use the below approach as well. It doesn't construct the .SD and is thus faster:

```
dtable4g[dtable4g[, .I[which.max(freq)], by = key]$V1]
```

Comment: this worked. But it took a very long time. My DT has 5.4 mil rows. I read in another thread that using .SD will slow things down.

Comment: see second approach in edit without .SD